# Thread waiting in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am implementing a parallel code in C with pthreads. Right now I am trying mixed operation on a specific data structure with mutex locks. Say for example I have a data set of 5,00,000 and I have employed 4 threads to insert into the structure and 4 threads to delete from it parallely (the whole data). I need the 4 threads of deletion to start only after the 4 threads of insertion have completed atleast 30 - 50 % portion of the data to be inserted. Is it possible to delay the threads? Can the condition format of pthreads be used for the same? Any resources leading to the same if provided will be useful.

A sample code:

```
thds = (pthread_t *)malloc((nthdsIns + nthdsDel - 1) * sizeof(pthread_t));
thdArg = (tArg *)malloc((nthdsIns + nthdsDel - 1) * sizeof(tArg));

for(i = 0; i < nthdsIns; i++){
    thdArg[i].num = numsIns; // array of elements to be inserted
    thdArg[i].start = i * iterIns; //starting index
    if(nthdsIns == 1)
        thdArg[i].end = nValIns-1; //ending index
    else
        thdArg[i].end = (i+1) * iterIns - 1;
}

for(k=0; k < nthdsIns; k++)
    pthread_create(&thds[k], NULL, pThdIns, &thdArg[k]);//spawning threads

temp = k;

/*Need to put some condition here inorder to allow the insertion threads to complete half of the insertion part*/



for(j = i, k = 0; k < nthdsDel; j++, k++){
    thdArg[j].num = numsDel;//array for deletion
    thdArg[j].start = k * iterIns;
    thdArg[j].end = (k+1) * iterIns - 1;
}

for(k = 0, j = temp; k < nthdsDel; k++, j++)
    pthread_create(&thds[j], NULL, pThdDel, &thdArg[j]);//spawning threads

for(i=0; i < (nthdsIns + nthdsDel); i++)
    pthread_join(thds[i], NULL);//joining threads
```

Comment: The idea of SO is to solve specific coding issues. A good question should be backed by an example showing the latter. General tutorials can be found in books or the net.

Comment: @alk, I am doing coding on concurrent skiplist, so in that case I am getting issue of segmentation fault, as the delete function goes on checking for element large amount of time, in a loop. So I was thinking, if its possible to enter some elements first and then proceed with deletion

Comment: So why not show us a minimal example of what you actually are coding then?

Comment: @alk, will putting a counter that is incremented atomically (using __sync_fetch_and_add()) during insertion be used in the area of code commented above to satisfy the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [condition variables](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=condvar&sektion=9)(condvar), [mutices](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html) etc to synchronize your threads.

```
delete()
{
  wait_on_cond();
  take_lock();
  actual_insert();
  release_loc();
}

insert()
{
  take_lock();
  actual_insert()
  release_lock();
  signal_condition();
}
```

This is basic idea on how can one use conditions. You need to check the actual documentation of library you plan to use.